# JasperReports localization

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using *JasperReports* and want to generate report in different languages but there is a problem occurred.

And this is my code

```java
public void initQueryReport() throws JRException, ParseException {
    try {
        Map param = new HashMap();
        param.put("DATE", date2);
        fill1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                "E:\\jasper reports\\employees.jasper", param, connection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}

ServletResponse respnce;
HttpServletResponse respons;

public void PDFQuery(ActionEvent event) throws JRException, IOException, ParseException {
    try {
        initQueryReport();
        respnce = (ServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        respons = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        respons.setContentType("application/pdf");
        respons.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
        respons.setContentType("application/pdf");
        ServletOutputStream out = respnce.getOutputStream();
        JRPdfExporter pdf = new JRPdfExporter();
        pdf.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, fill1);
        pdf.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);

        pdf.exportReport();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I created a properties file with name ***localizationdemo.prperties*** contains text I want in the language used and I put this file in *`src`* folder.

When I run the application and click link that generates the report the following exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No input source supplied to the exporter
```

Note when I run the application in debugging mode i have the following exception details:

```
java.util.missingresourceexception can't find bundle for base name locale en_us
```

Please help me to solve this problem. And thx a lot

Comment: You should put properties file in class path

Comment: Try to rename file name, for example ***localizationdemo_en.properties***

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you've set the resource bundle property in the .jrxml file as it seems that you haven't set it in your java-file?

If you're using Jaspersoft Studio: In Jaspersoft Studio click on the report name in the *outline*, then select from the *property view* the menu "Report" and check if under the submenu 'Dataset' the property for the Resource Bundle (localizationdemo) has been set to the appropriate properties file.

You can also check it in the Source View, where it should be like this:

```
<jasperReport /*****/ resourceBundle="localizationdemo" /****/>
```

Further infos: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_Internationalization.htm

Answer (score 0):

are you using Spring frameWork?  may be if you use **ResourceBundleViewResolver** in spring.xml. you have to put path **localizationdemo.properties** located in as basename property value.      look my following code in spring.xml :

```
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver"

property name="basename" value="config/jasperreports-views"
```

**in my case,  I used spring 3.0**